# How to use a MVC 'View' in Slim?

Tags: php, model-view-controller, slim

```
$app->get('/', function () {
  // Initial page load.
  include 'body-index.php';
  return $response;
});
```

I have the code above on my /index.php. How would I then call and modify functions within body-index.php? As I'm learning MVCs and frameworks right now on my own I'd rather do it this way, rather then breaking out of Slim and do a `get('/body-index.php',` with the page code. Is this possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From **Slim Framework documentation**:

> Most often, you’ll need to write to the PSR 7 Response object. You can write content to the StreamInterface instance with its write() method like this:

```
$body = $response->getBody();
$body->write('Hello');
```

> You can also replace the PSR 7 Response object’s body with an entirely new StreamInterface instance. This is particularly useful when you want to pipe content from a remote destination (e.g. the filesystem or a remote API) into the HTTP response. You can replace the PSR 7 Response object’s body with its withBody(StreamInterface $body) method. Its argument MUST be an instance of \Psr\Http\Message\StreamInterface.

```
$newStream = new \GuzzleHttp\Psr7\LazyOpenStream('/path/to/file', 'r');
$newResponse = $oldResponse->withBody($newStream);
```

Source: [Response - Slim Framework](http://www.slimframework.com/docs/objects/response.html#the-response-body)

Comment: I *had* read this in the documentation but didn't realize it was what I needed. Thanks much. :)